# Need an example of a DFA with large number of states?

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

I am trying to parallelize the regular expression matching process. I have implemented the algorithm and all, what I need now is a real world problem (deterministic finite automaton) with a large number of states, so I could do some benchmarking of my algorithm. By that, I mean a problem that is known for taking plenty of memory and processing time. 
Please feel free to share any example of DFA with more than 100 states.

Comment: Try finding a handful of substrings of DNA in a large sequence of DNA.

Comment: ... or all the SQL keywords in a large corpus of english text.

Comment: draw a [DFA for divide by 'large number' e.g. 101](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22282792/1673391)