# Binary division and DFA

Tags: finite-automata, automata, deterministic

wanted to know whether binary division concept come from DFA i.e. from finite automata?

According to me the dfa would have lead to the binary division bcz we do binary divisons in computers only and we know that dfa have forms the base of computers operations so after having large sample size based on finite automata conclusion would have come that binary divsion would have come through xor operation which forms the base of the same.

Comment: *nomen est omen* I guess

Comment: Huh?  What do either of these have to do with the other?

Comment: @oliver DFA could be used for Binary division.

Comment: It is better to not answer than down vote the question, that's not encouraging. There r few ppl here looking for questions not to answer. Everyone can't be genius and be genius  just not to answer.

Comment: @skyconfusion DFA (or NFA) outputs in binary - "Yes" or "No" (accepted or rejected) only, so if you are looking the check weather a binary string is divisible by a number say 'n' or not that answer to your question is : yes  --check this [Design DFA accepting binary strings divisible by a number 'n'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897554/design-dfa-accepting-binary-strings-divisible-by-a-number-n/22282792#22282792) but if you wants to divide two numbers you need moor and mealy machines machine too check http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~coquand/AUTOMATA/book.pdf  read Page 495

Comment: @Grijesh Thank you, I was looking for something like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design DFA accepting binary strings divisible by a number 'n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897554/design-dfa-accepting-binary-strings-divisible-by-a-number-n)