# How to design a DFA that accepts string1,2,3, and the sum is divided by 6?

Tags: computer-science, dfa, nfa

How to design a NDF that accepts string1,2,3, and the sum is divided by 6?
For example, 223311 is accepted and 322 is not accecpted. Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: This site is not a free do-my-homework service.

Comment: Indeed, as @RolandIllig says, this sounds like a homework assignment you got in a formal languages / grammars class. If there's something you don't undetstand about the _concepts_, the formal _definitions_, you could ask about that... although, frankly, [CS.SX](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) might be better suited for DFA/NFA-related questions these days.

Comment: read = [Design DFA accepting binary strings divisible by a number 'n'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897554/design-dfa-accepting-binary-strings-divisible-by-a-number-n/22282792#22282792)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a "please do my homework" question.